# Python ffmpeg subprocess never exits on Linux, works on Windows

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I wonder if someone can help explain what is happening?

I run 2 subprocesses, 1 for ffprobe and 1 for ffmpeg.

```
popen = subprocess.Popen(ffprobecmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

And

```
popen = subprocess.Popen(ffmpegcmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

On both Windows and Linux the ffprobe command fires, finishes and gets removed from taskmanager/htop. But only on Windows does the same happen to ffmpeg. On Linux the command remains in htop...

[image]

Can anyone explain what is going on, if it matters and how I can stop it from happening please?

EDIT: Here are the commands...

```
ffprobecmd = 'ffprobe' + \
' -user_agent "' + request.headers['User-Agent'] + '"' + \
' -headers "Referer: ' + request.headers['Referer'] + '"' + \
' -timeout "5000000"' + \
' -v error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=height -of default=nw=1:nk=1' + \
' -i "' + request.url + '"'
```

and

```
ffmpegcmd = 'ffmpeg' + \
' -re' + \
' -user_agent "' + r.headers['User-Agent'] + '"' + \
' -headers "Referer: ' + r.headers['Referer'] + '"' + \
' -timeout "10"' + \
' -i "' + r.url + '"' + \
' -c copy' + \
' -f mpegts' + \
' pipe:'
```

EDIT: Here is a example that behaves as described...

```
import flask
from flask import Response
import subprocess

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def go():
    def stream(ffmpegcmd):
        popen = subprocess.Popen(ffmpegcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        try:
            for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
                yield stdout_line
        except GeneratorExit:
            raise

    url = "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8"

    ffmpegcmd = 'ffmpeg' + \
                ' -re' + \
                ' -timeout "10"' + \
                ' -i "' + url + '"' + \
                ' -c copy' + \
                ' -f mpegts' + \
                ' pipe:'
    return Response(stream(ffmpegcmd))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: Note that this code has some significant security problems. What do you expect to happen if a Referrer contains `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`, for example? (The possibility of there being single quotes _as part of the data itself_ means you can't just add literal single quotes during the concatenation process to rule out issues).

Comment: ...particularly for UNIX-y systems, you'd be a lot better off forming a list and using `shell=False` instead of going the string route at all.

Comment: As for your ffmpeg command not exiting... are you actually reading to the end of the FIFO? I'd also suggest `stdin=subprocesss.DEVNULL` so it can't be blocking on stdin. However, this can't really be given a canonical answer without a [mre] -- code that can be run without any changes whatsoever to let someone else see the problem themselves and test whether the issue is resolved.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply. I have added a stripped down basic example that behave the same way for me.

Comment: So, when I run that [mre], what I see is that the copy of ffmpeg _is actually exiting_, but Python isn't reaping its PID from the process table so it's stuck there as a zombie.

Comment: But that's different from what your screenshot shows, because your screenshot has S state instead of Z state.

Comment: Now, what we _can_ do, quite certainly, is shut down the process gracefully from inside the exception handler.

Comment: The other thing you can do is to stop the copies of `sh` from running either by changing to use a list instead of a string and using `shell=False`, or changing the command from just `ffmpeg` to `exec ffmpeg`.

Comment: I was doing some reading and actually just came across the exec option which does get rid of the sh showing in htop and does show the process as Z after the generator exits. How to I shut down the zombie process though? I have tried `except GeneratorExit: popen.terminate()` and `except GeneratorExit: popen.kill()`

Comment: You can't kill a zombie; it's already dead. That's the whole point of what a zombie _is_.

Comment: ...a zombie process is also called a "tombstone" -- it's just a marker of what used to be there, holding information about how it died. Don't use `except GeneratorExit` for that; a `finally` is much more appropriate -- we want to handle the case even when there was no exception thrown at all (and `GeneratorExit` isn't part of the usual interface for something viewing a generator through the lens of an iterable; the lower-level interface throws it when `next()` is called but there's nothing left, but the high-level one doesn't see it at all).

Comment: So, all you have to do to remove a zombie from your process table is just _read its state_. Anything that calls the `waitpid()` syscall -- as `popen.poll()` does -- will reap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the extra `sh` process due to `shell=True`, and your copies of ffmpeg are allowed to try to attach to the original terminal's stdin because you aren't overriding that file handle. To fix both those issues, and also some security bugs, switch to `shell=False`, set `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`, and (to stop zombies from potentially being left behind, note the `finally:` block below that calls `popen.poll()` to see if the child exited, and `popen.terminate()` to *tell* it to exit if it hasn't):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import flask
from flask import Response
import subprocess

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def go():
    def stream(ffmpegcmd):
        popen = subprocess.Popen(ffmpegcmd, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        try:
            # NOTE: consider reading fixed-sized blocks (4kb at least) at a time
            # instead of parsing binary streams into "lines".
            for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
                yield stdout_line
        finally:
            if popen.poll() == None:
                popen.terminate()
                popen.wait() # yes, this can cause things to actually block

    url = "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8"

    ffmpegcmd = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-re',
        '-timeout', '10',
        '-i', url,
        '-c', 'copy',
        '-f', 'mpegts',
        'pipe:'
    ]
    return Response(stream(ffmpegcmd))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

Mind, it's not appropriate to be parsing a binary stream as a series of lines at all. It would be much more appropriate to use blocks (and to change your response headers so the browser knows to parse the content as a video).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am still seeing zombie processes when I exit the player (I am using VLC). I am interesting in looking into returning blocks but the content type isn't needed for me because my programs know what to do with the response. I assume you mean setting the mimetype?

Comment: The HTTP header that gets the mime type is called `Content-Type`, so yes.

Comment: Sorry, I waited a while for the zombie to go away and it didnt. But restarting htop and its no longer there... So its working... I think

Comment: If you want to be extra sure, you might keep a list of subprocess objects to occasionally `poll()` until they finish dying (if you end up in the `popen.terminate()` case, you can still get a zombie, since the terminate() takes some time to take effect, and the poll() happened before it).

Comment: BTW, the usual way to make sure you don't have zombies is to have a SIGCHILD handler that calls `wait()` to reap them; but doing that can break other things if you have code that _assumes_ it'll be able to successfully `wait()` for a dead child (outside that signal handler) and find out how it died. Of course, if you have the signal handler update an internal table of jobs with how they died... then you just reinvented half of bash's job control.

Comment: I ended up just taking out the `except GeneratorExit: raise`; I'm unconvinced that it ever does anything useful.

Comment: Using the list arguments, what would be the equivalent of this... ```' -headers "Referer: ' + request.headers['Referer'] + '"' + \```

Comment: @Chris, `[..., '-headers', f"Referer: {request.headers['Referer']}", ...]` is one of the many possible ways to do it.

Comment: Sorry I had already figured it out. I just assumed it was an issue when the issue was elsewhere. I used  ```'-headers', 'Referer: ' + r.headers['Referer'],```

Comment: and so far so good. Not seeing any zombie or leftover instances of ffmpeg. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What type is the `ffmpegcmd` variable? Is it a string or a list/sequence?

Note that Windows and Linux/POSIX behave differently with the `shell=True` parameter enabled or disabled. It matters whether `ffmpegcmd` is a string or a list.

Direct excerpt from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a
> string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
> This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
> when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
> backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a
> sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
> additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
> itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> `Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])`
>
> On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies
> the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on
> Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the
> shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch
> file or console-based executable.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the commands. I have been creating and testing my python code on Windows, but I deploy it on my Linux server inside a Docker container.